# Spacing problems with enumitem and amsthm

Tags: spacing, lists, theorems, enumitem

There are already plenty of answered questions on how to replace

```
Theorem.    * Point
    * Point
    * Point
```

by

```
Theorem. * Point
    * Point
    * Point
```

Now, for short theorem headers, I want to achieve

```
Theorem. * Point
         * Point
         * Point
```

However, my attempt does not perfectly work out: The first bullet point is slightly more left than the others. Which length did I forget to take into account? MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,amsthm}
\begin{document}
\newlength{\algnRef}
\settowidth{\algnRef}{\textbf{Fact.} {}}
\addtolength{\algnRef}{1em}
\setlist{leftmargin=\algnRef}
\newtheorem*{fact*}{Fact}
\begin{fact*}
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em]
        \item Bla
    \end{itemize}
    \vspace{-\topsep}
    \vspace{\parsep}
    \vspace{\itemsep}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Bla
        \item Bla
    \end{itemize}
\end{fact*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of confusion was the fact that `amsthm` does not place a space after $\textbf{Fact.}$, which would be 3.33pt if normal weight and 3.83pt in boldface, but rather places a skip of 5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt. Therefore, the following code compiles correctly:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{calc,enumitem,amsthm}
\begin{document}

\newtheoremstyle{plain}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {1ex}       % HEADSPACE
  {}          % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem*{fact*}{Fact}
\setlist{leftmargin={\widthof{\textbf{Fact.}}+1em+1ex}}
\setlist[itemize]{label=$\mid$}

\begin{fact*}
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em]
        \item Bla
    \end{itemize}
    \vspace{-2\topsep}
    \vspace{\parsep}
    \vspace{\itemsep}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Bla
        \item Bla
    \end{itemize}
\end{fact*}
\end{document}
```

Note that I have placed pipe symbols as bulletpoints to make the horizontal alignment more visible.